# Regular Expression For Telephone Number

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I have regular expression in `regular expression validator control`. It supports telephone number like this for example **+359111111111**. The symbol **+** is mandatory. I want to allow with the start of **0** or **+** and then the phone number.

What I have now is:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revGroupTelephone" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7,11}$"
                     Text="*" ErrorMessage="Wrong number" ControlToValidate="tbGroupTelephone" ValidationGroup="validOrg" />
```

Comment: So is the `+` mandatory or not? Also, shouldn't the number of allowed digits vary if there is a `+` or a `0` in the first place?

Comment: No I want to allow 0 or + in front of the number. One of the both to be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `|` for an "or" clause : see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#alternation_constructs)

So I would replace

`\+`

by

```
(\+|0)
```

Comment: So the whole expression is ^(\+|0)[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7,11}$ ?

Comment: Well, I didn't look the whole expression, but if the rest is satisfying for you, yes.